# How to read multiline file of numbers into 1-dimensional numpy array?

Tags: numpy

I have some numbers in a file

```
   8.89661443042575        17.8003874198066        17.8003323639473
   43.9969250561223        4.51593232168458        0.000000000000000E+000
   0.000000000000000E+000  0.000000000000000E+000
```

What would be the most canonical way to read these in so that the result is a 1-dimensional numpy array of numbers, 8 elements long?

Comment: @gelezko The docs say ```Each row in the text file must have the same number of values.``` which is invalid for the example.

Comment: @gelezko Have you tried this?  Did you not get the error "ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 3"?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    a = np.array([float(field) for field in f.read().split()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient code (i assume), but it works:

```
import numpy as np

a = []
with open('file.txt') as temp_file:
    for i in temp_file:
        a.append(i.split())  # removes whitespaces and split into one list per row
np_array = np.asarray([float(item) for sublist in a for item in sublist])  # flatten, str->float, create-array
```

Answer (score 0):

With floating-point numbers in a file `floats.txt`

```bash
   8.89661443042575        17.8003874198066        17.8003323639473
   43.9969250561223        4.51593232168458        0.000000000000000E+000
   0.000000000000000E+000  0.000000000000000E+000
```

You can read the numbers into a 1D array with

```py
import numpy as np

with open("floats.txt", "r") as f:
    arr = np.fromstring(f.read(), sep=" ")

print(f"{arr = }")
# arr = array([ 8.89661443, 17.80038742, 17.80033236, 43.99692506,  4.51593232,
#        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ])
```

With integers in a file `ints.txt`

```bash
9 10 5
8 9 10 5 12 15
7 3 5
```

use `dtype=int` to specify the data type

```py
import numpy as np

with open("ints.txt", "r") as f:
    arr = np.fromstring(f.read(), sep=" ", dtype=int)

print(f"{arr = }")
# arr = array([ 9, 10,  5,  8,  9, 10,  5, 12, 15,  7,  3,  5])
```